# Flutter Firebase Analytics: No implementation found for method setCurrentScreen

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

Been looking around haven't find any fix for this problem with flutter:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setCurrentScreen on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_analytics)

Using firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6 in my flutter dependencies.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/e4sph7/firebase_analytics/

Answer (score 0):

In your android/app/build.gradle file set the minSdkVersion 21
or
add this implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0" in your dependencies at android/app/build.gradle file

from : https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1401

The second option worked for me I guess because I made the migration to AndroidX.

My suggestion to you is to make the AndroidX migration and then try the second option.

Answer (score 0):

i look this pubspec.yaml documentation example "https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-flutter/tree/main/analytics" and see no difference with the enviroment sdk and dependencies versions.. and still get error, until i run "flutter clean" on terminal and then works.